# How do I choose IF for a GPS/GNSS RF Front-end?

Tags: rf, gps, gnss

This is a follow-on from this [fascinating question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512269/max2769-xtal-reference-frequency) on selecting a TCXO (or entire frequency plan) for a GNSS SDR RF front-end. (I also have another follow-up question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558347/why-is-a-low-resolution-adc-e-g-4-bits-a-bad-idea-for-a-zero-if-gps-gnss-rf-f)).

The [MAX2769](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/wireless-rf/MAX2769.html) and [MAX2771](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/wireless-rf/MAX2771.html) EVKs both use 16.368MHz for their reference, which is a nice easy multiplier to GPS L1 = 16.368 * 96.25 = 1575.42MHz and L2 = 75 * 1227.6MHz for the mixer.

However, from the answer to the referenced questions, there are two comments that stand out:

> Different frequency plans allow you to reduce beating from quantization noise, on the other hand they may introduce spurs in the IF from the fractional PLL. If you want to squeeze out the last decibel, I would try to avoid the prime factor 1023 in XTALS and go for a more elaborate setup.

Why is this the case, and what might a more elaborate setup look like? I've noticed that U-Blox (at least in past generations) use 26MHz for their TCXO, and NovAtel use a 20MHz VCXO, implying that they do have a more sophisticated frequency plan.

Similarly, what are the implications for choosing an ADC sampling frequency that is/isn't synchronous to the GPS chipping rate?

Comment: Hello Damien, I hope I find the time to share my thoughts on this. I concede that my considerations may not be relevant for the general case, because the overall concept of GPS localization is so robust, the output of a receiver will hardly ever be affected by such minute optimizations. Nevertheless, the concepts of GNSS signal processing are fascinating.

Comment: Hello @Andreas, I was hoping you might answer! I'm looking forward to an answer - I am always interested design trade-offs.

Comment: Comment since this is only tangentially related and not a complete answer, but Tran in Chapter 8 of this [thesis](https://unsworks.unsw.edu.au/fapi/datastream/unsworks:45315/SOURCE02?view=true) looks at dithering techniques to mitigate the problems of "commensurate sampling" (which looks to be the name used in literature for sampling that is an integer multiple of the chipping rate). There's a bunch of citations there to investigate further.