# Why is a low resolution ADC (e.g. 4-bits) a bad idea for a Zero-IF GPS/GNSS RF front-end?

Tags: rf, adc, gps, gnss

This is another follow-up from this [fascinating question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512269/max2769-xtal-reference-frequency) (the other follow-up question is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558342/how-do-i-choose-if-for-a-gps-gnss-receiver?noredirect=1&lq=1)) for the design of an RF front-end for a GPS/GNSS SDR receiver.

In a comment to the accepted answer, it was noted that:

> Zero IF is a bad idea with a 4-bit A/D. Remember you get a rounding error for every sample and for zero IF, this error will also have low frequency. This is what I call beating.

My (clearly incomplete) understanding was that in the absence of interference, GPS only required low-resolution ADCs in order to be effective - I seem to recall the degradation in C/N0 for a 3-bit receiver being in the order of 0.1-0.2dB.

On this basis, why would the [MAX2769](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/wireless-rf/MAX2769.html) and [MAX2771](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/comms/wireless-rf/MAX2771.html) (shown below) provide I- and Q-mixers, but only 2-bit ADCs on the I and Q channels?  Is this configuration only intended to be run with an external ADC? If so, what resolution would be required?

Otherwise, it would seem that the sensible solution would be to [choose some IF frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558342/how-do-i-choose-if-for-a-gps-gnss-receiver?noredirect=1&lq=1), and take advantage of the 3-bit I-only ADC resolution.

[image: MAX2771 RF front-end]

Comment: Are you aware of the relation between ADC resolution and **sampling rate**? In my view, anyone who says: "Zero IF is a bad idea with a 4-bit A/D." Doesn't understand this relation. **MANY** ADCs are only **1-bit** (sigma-delta / delta-sigma) ADCs.

Comment: The idea is to use processing gain from CDMA correlation. Since the band of interest is "just white noise" (in the absence of interference), the required dynamic range is constant.  Many consumer GPS receivers use 1-bit sampling and dispense with with an ADC (and AGC) altogether, but I have never heard of any of those mixing direct to baseband.

Comment: GPS uses CDM, not CDMA. Your comment doesn't address the points I made at all. I have worked on the design of many transceiver systems yet your comments do not make much sense to me. My feeling is that you might need to follow a course on RF receiver design.

Comment: Both of your links in the first sentence go to the same question.

Comment: @Hearth, I've fixed the link. Thanks!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, The course on RF receiver design might ba good idea - otherwise I would not be asking these sort of questions. Any suggestions? I've got a handle on the *math* GPS acquisition and tracking and have the basics of comms theory from almost 20 years ago, but this is the first time I have thought about an actual practical implementation.

Comment: RF design course: Have a look at: https://www.cei.se/continuing-education-institute/circuit-system-design.html  there are countless others. Do realize that these are expensive courses, it's usually paid for by your employer. You could also start by reading a book on **RF system design**, there are many, I have no book recommendations. Depending on what your goal is (building something or just educational) you could just use a GPS module, there is really no need to design your own system.

Comment: This is indeed educational (for a hobby, not for a university). The gap in my knowledge is the RF front-end and baseband and hence my little project. The goal is to learn what *really* happens before a receiver outputs pseudoranges.

Comment: MAX2769 and MAX2771 do not feature Sigma-Delta-ADCs, in fact there is no quantization error feedback whatsoever. Even if there was, "supersampling" at 50Msps (the maximum rate) and filtering would not help much with the resolution. You cannot get rid of the quantization error if it is low frequency. If it is high frequency, it's easily filtered by low pass filters (such as the integration period boxcar filter). Quantization noise (for phase in 2/2 bit complex ADC with 33% magnitude bit set) is a 12*IF sawtooth. Consider its harmonics and subsampled images thereof and youre done.

Comment: @Andreas, this comment is the start of a very good answer. In the meantime, is there a canonical reference (papers/books) that you would recommend?